# ToggleButton Color Changer

Tags: delphi, togglebutton, tms, tms-web-core

I have a ToggleButton like this

[image: ToggleButton]

I would like to change the color on both sides of the ToggleButton in order to represent light/dark modes

Hi there, I have just started using TMS Web core and would like to incorporate a light/dark mode using a ToggleButton, how can I change the color on both sides of the ToggleButton in order to represent the light/dark mode?

Answer (score 0):

So changing the color on a `TWebToggleButton` is a big job! Great question though, because the component doesn't have any properties available to do this in design-time.

First, I made a function to change the color:

```
procedure ChangeToggleButtonColor(aToggleButton: TWebToggleButton; aColor: TColor);
var
  aBtn: TJSHTMLElement;
  aBtnSlider: TJSNode;
  aBtnColor: String;
begin
  aBtnColor := '#' + IntToHex(GetRValue(aColor), 2) + IntToHex(GetGValue(aColor), 2) + IntToHex(GetBValue(aColor), 2) ;
  aBtn := aToggleButton.ElementHandle;
  aBtnSlider := aBtn.getElementsByClassName(aToggleButton.Name + '_slider').item(0);
  asm
    aBtnSlider.style["background-color"] = aBtnColor;
  end;
end;
```

You pass in the `TWebToggleButton` and the `TColor` for it. That will successfully change the color.

Then you need to set a default/starting color for the `TWebToggleButton` on the form's `OnCreate` event:

```
procedure TForm1.WebFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebToggleButton.Checked := False;
  ChangeToggleButtonColor(WebToggleButton, clRed);
end;
```

And then on the `TWebToggleButton`'s `onClick` event, you need to change the color every time the user clicks on it as well:

```
procedure TForm1.WebToggleButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (TWebToggleButton(Sender).Checked) then
    ChangeToggleButtonColor(TWebToggleButton(Sender), clBlue)
  else
    ChangeToggleButtonColor(TWebToggleButton(Sender), clRed);
end;
```

And that's it. Now you should have a `TWebToggleButton` with a custom color set for both sides (Checked and not Checked).

Not Checked:
[image: TWebToggleButton Checked]

Checked:
[image: TWebToggleButton Not Checked]